# Very simple pandas column/row transform that I cannot figure out

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to do a simple calculation on values in a dataframe, but I need some column transposed first. Once they are transposed I want to take the most recent amount / 2nd most recent amount and then the binary result if it less than or equal to .5

By most recent I mean most recent to the date in the Date 2 column

```
Have This

| Name | Amount |  Date 1                | Date 2     |
| -----| ----   |------------------------|------------|
| Jim  | 100    |   2021-06-10           | 2021-06-15 |
| Jim  | 200    |   2021-05-11           | 2021-06-15 |
| Jim  | 150    |   2021-03-5            | 2021-06-15 |
| Bob  | 350    |   2022-06-10           | 2022-08-30 |
| Bob  | 300    |   2022-08-12           | 2022-08-30 |
| Bob  | 400    |   2021-07-6            | 2022-08-30 |

I Want this
| Name | Amount | Date 2| Most Recent Amount(MRA) | 2nd Most Recent Amount(2MRA) | MRA / 2MRA| Less than or equal to .5 |
| -----| -------|------------------------|----------------|--------------------|-------------|--------------------------|
| Jim  | 100    |   2021-06-15           |       100      |       200          | .5          | 1                        |
| Bob  | 300    |   2022-08-30           |       300      |       350          | .85         | 0                        |
```

Comment: how did you choose the Amount for Bob as 300? All the `Date 2` are the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the original dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Jim','Jim','Jim','Bob','Bob','Bob'],
               'Amount':[100,200,150,350,300,400],
               'Date 1':['2021-06-10','2021-05-11','2021-03-05','2022-06-10','2022-08-12','2021-07-06'],
               'Date 2':['2021-06-15','2021-06-15','2021-06-15','2022-08-30','2022-08-30','2022-08-30']
              })
```

And this is the results.

```
# here we take the gropby of the 'Name' column
g = df.sort_values('Date 1', ascending=False).groupby(['Name'])

# then we use the agg function to get the first of 'Date 2' and 'Amount' columns
# and then rename result of the 'Amount' column to 'MRA' 
first = g.agg({'Date 2':'first','Amount':'first'}).rename(columns={'Amount':'MRA'}).reset_index()
# Similarly, we take the second values by applying a lambda function
second = g.agg({'Date 2':'first','Amount':lambda t: t.iloc[1]}).rename(columns={'Amount':'2MRA'}).reset_index()
df_T = pd.merge(first, second, on=['Name','Date 2'], how='left')

# then we use this function to add two desired columns
def operator(x):
    return x['MRA']/x['2MRA'], [1 if x['MRA']/x['2MRA']<=.5 else 0][0]

# we apply the operator function to add 'MRA/2MRA' and 'Less than or equal to .5' columns
df_T['MRA/2MRA'], df_T['Less than or equal to .5'] = zip(*df_T.apply(operator, axis=1))
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: This works great thank you! Do you think you could explain a little bit more about how it works? Still kind of new and wanting to learn.

Comment: I added some explanatory comments. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do what you've asked is:

```py
df = ( df[df['Date 1'] <= df['Date 2']]
        .groupby('Name', sort=False)['Date 1'].nlargest(2)
        .reset_index(level=0)
        .assign(**{
            'Amount': df.Amount, 
            'Date 2': df['Date 2'],
            'recency': ['MRA','MRA2']*len(set(df.Name.tolist()))
        })
        .pivot(index=['Name','Date 2'], columns='recency', values='Amount')
        .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None) )
df = df.assign(**{'Amount':df.MRA, 'MRA / MRA2': df.MRA/df.MRA2})
df = df.assign(**{'Less than or equal to .5': (df['MRA / MRA2'] <= 0.5).astype(int)})
df = pd.concat([df[['Name', 'Amount']], df.drop(columns=['Name', 'Amount'])], axis=1)
```

Input:

```
  Name  Amount     Date 1     Date 2
0  Jim     100 2021-06-10 2021-06-15
1  Jim     200 2021-05-11 2021-06-15
2  Jim     150 2021-03-05 2021-06-15
3  Bob     350 2022-06-10 2022-08-30
4  Bob     300 2022-08-12 2022-08-30
5  Bob     400 2021-07-06 2022-08-30
```

Output:

```
  Name  Amount     Date 2  MRA  MRA2  MRA / MRA2  Less than or equal to .5
0  Bob     300 2022-08-30  300   350    0.857143                         0
1  Jim     100 2021-06-15  100   200    0.500000                         1
```

Explanation:

- Filter only for rows where `Date 1` <= `Date 2`
- Use `groupby()` and `nlargest()` to get the 2 most recent `Date 1` values per `Name`
- Use `assign()` to add back the `Amount` and `Date 2` columns and create a `recency` column containing `MRA` and `MRA2` for the pair of rows corresponding to each `Name` value
- Use `pivot()` to turn the `recency` values `MRA` and `MRA2` into column labels
- Use `reset_index()` to restore `Name` and `Date 2` to columns, and use `rename_axis()` to make the `columns` index anonymous
- Use `assign()` once to restore `Amount` and add column `MRA / MRA2`, and again to add column named `Less than or equal to .5`
- Use `concat()`, `[]` and `drop()` to rearrange the columns to match the output sequence shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the rough procedure you want:

1. `sort_values` by Name and Date 1 to get the data in order.
2. `shift` to get the previous date and 2nd most recent amount fields
3. Filter the dataframe for Date 1 <= Date 2.
4. `group_by` by Name and use `head` to get only the first row.

Now, your Amount column is your Most Recent Amount and your Shifted Amount column is the 2nd Most Recent amount. From there, you can do a simple division to get the ratio.

Comment: Could you possible type up an example? I am not familiar with shift.